# Jquery Validation not work with wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, validation

I am trying to use jquery Validation in a plugin.

This my integration code:

```
function addscripts( $hook ) { 

           wp_register_script( 'JqueryFile', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/Js/jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery') );
           wp_enqueue_script( 'JqueryFile' );

           wp_register_script( 'ValidationJ', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/Js/jquery.validate.min.js', array( 'jquery') ); 
           wp_enqueue_script( 'ValidationJ' );

           wp_register_script( 'Managment', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/Js/managment.js', array( 'jquery') );
           wp_enqueue_script( 'Managment' );

 }
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'addscripts' );
```

The file managment.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $("#add_new_collector").validate({
    rules: {
      collector_name: {
      minlength: 10,
      required: true
    },submitHandler: add_collector
  });
```

Adding function

```
   function add_collector(){
                var data = $("#add_new_collector").serialize();
                alert(data);
    }
    });
```

The Validation is not working

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to take the function add_collector out of the $(document).ready to make it visible to the submit

Also you are missing a bracket:

```js
function add_collector() {
  var data = $("#add_new_collector").serialize();
  alert(data);
}
$(function() {
  $("#add_new_collector").validate({
      rules: {
        collector_name: {
          minlength: 10,
          required: true
        }
      },
      submitHandler: add_collector
    }
  });
});
```

or just

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add_new_collector").validate({
    rules: {
      collector_name: {
        minlength: 10,
        required: true
      },
      submitHandler: function() {
        var data = $("#add_new_collector").serialize();
        alert(data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```